# How to prevent mouseleave from firing when an element is following the mouse?

Tags: jquery

The code below moves a `div` to the correct height upon `mouseenter` of another element (which I will refer to as 'container' from now on), then as the mouse moves it adjusts the `left` position of the element so that it follows the mouse left and right.

Finally when the mouse leaves the container div, the element is hidden.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave mousemove', '.seek-bar', function (e) {
    var $seeker = $('#seek-head');

    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        var top = Number($(this).offset().top);
        $seeker.css({ top: top + 'px' }).show();
    }
    else if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
        $seeker.hide();
    }

    if (e.type == 'mousemove') {
        var x = e.pageX;
        $seeker.css({ left: x + 'px' });
    }
});
```

Although this works fine, the element flashes due to the mouse being over `$seeker` rather than the container element. The `mouseleave` event is being fired when I don't wan't it to be.

How can I prevent this?

Please Note:  The `$seeker` element is directly in the `<body>` so will always be 'in front' of the container element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrote you code a litte, but why don't you put the `mouseleave` on the element that is infront of the container element?

```
var $seeker = $('#seek-head');    
$('body').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var top = Number($(this).offset().top);
        $seeker.css({ top: top + 'px' }).show();
    },
    mousemove: function() {
        var x = e.pageX;
        $seeker.css({ left: x + 'px' });
    }
}, '.seek-bar');

$('body').on('mouseleave', $seeker, function() {
    $seeker.hide();
});
```

Comment: I thought this worked at first (i had to add 'e' inside the mousemove call so tat e.pageX could pick it up), until I realised that the 'mouseleave event isn't getting called at all when the mouse leaves the '.seek-bar'.  Any idea how to rectifiy this? Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ahh.. it is because your code calls 'mouseleave on the $seeker element rather than the container element which is '.seek-head'.  With this modified, your code produces exactly the same result as my own i'm afriad.  Thanks for trying however.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, would it be a suggestion to put a div on top of the bar and the seeker and use that as "click area" ?

Comment: If you only support modern browsers with CSS3 you could also go for `#seek-head { pointer-events: none };`

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about that css function!  That works perfectly.  What I have done is combine 'pointer-events:none;' with using a small 2px offset for the element from the mousepointer.  This gives perfect behaviour in modern browsers and near perfect behaviour on old ones.